# Posting values to server in Android using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a registration page for my application and have got all the values stored in a

```
List<Pair<String,String>>
```

I've passed this through to my Class for connection to the server via an ASyncTask however after creating a HttpUrlConnection, i'm not sure how to add these parameters to my URL Connection. Every that i've looked uses NamePairValues but from the research i have performed this has been deprecated.

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            String username = params[0];
            String firstName = params[1];
            String lastName = params[2];
            String email = params[3];
            String password = params[4];

            ConnectionHandler connection = new ConnectionHandler(ctx);

            List<Pair<String, String>> args = new ArrayList<>();
            args.add(new Pair<>("username", username));
            args.add(new Pair<>("first_name", firstName));
            args.add(new Pair<>("last_name", lastName));
            args.add(new Pair<>("email", email));
            args.add(new Pair<>("password", password));


            connection.makeConnection(REGISTER_URL, args);
            return null;
        }
```

That's my current doInBackground.

Is there an easier methoid than using `List<Pair<String,String>>`?

EDIT: I actually ended up using volley which made this some much easier to do.

Comment: Use Volley or Retrofit instead. HttpUrlConnection is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this later, I ended up using Volley which made the process so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as the example:

```
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);


        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://youurl.com.br");
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        String id= "" + 1
        String value = "value"
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", value);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs)); // add the pairs to post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post); // execute the request
```

Of course, wrap the logic in the appropriate try/catch blocks.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I removed the HttpConnection and changed it to use Volley, made a JSONRequest to the server sending my user details and returning the success or failure of the query. Thanks for everyone who answered,